# WCF Self Hosted no parallelism at first

Tags: wcf, service, parallel-processing, self, hosted

I have a self hosted WCF service with two methods:

```
     public async Task<string> MethodA()
     {
         return await Task.Run(() => samplesMain.MethodA());
     }

     public async Task<string> MethodB()
     {
         return await Task.Run(() => samplesMain.MethodB());
     }
```

Both methods are very simple:

```
     public string MethodA()
     {
         Thread.Sleep(10000);
         return "A";
     }

     public string MethodB()
     {
         Thread.Sleep(10000);
         return "B";
     }
```

From a TestClient If the first time I call MethodA, I also call MethodB, MethodB does not start until MethodA has finished. However, once both methods have been executed at least once, subsequent parallel calls to those methods are executed in parallel.

My ServiceBehavior:

[ServiceBehavior
(
ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple,
InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
UseSynchronizationContext = false
)
]

I've read that it could be due to not initially calling the "Open" method on the client, but I still don't get parallelism from the beginning. Why?

Comment: You can try **InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.percall**. It can create a new **InstanceContext** (and corresponding service object) for each client request. The role of a single is that a single InstanceContext (and the corresponding service object) handles all client requests during the lifetime of the application.

Comment: Later I found a problem where I was using **"Parallel.Invoke(client. MethodA, client. MethodB); "** to test your questions. I now think the problem may also be related to your client's call, can you post further how your client called?

Comment: PerCall is not a option because I create an instance serviceHost, not a type serviceHost.

My client is a WPF application with 2 buttons:
 private async void bMethodA_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string result = await client.MethodAAsync();
            tbResult.Text = result;
        }

        private async void bMethodB_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string result = await client.MethodBAsync();
            tbResult.Text = result;
        }
I do click in each one.

Thanks @QIYou

Comment: You mentioned above: **If the first time I call MethodA, I also call MethodB, MethodB does not start until MethodA has finished**. I think it's caused by **Thread.sleep()**. The **Thread.sleep** method is a synchronous method that causes the current thread to pause for a specified number of milliseconds or intervals until it times out or is canceled.

Comment: This means that the **Thread.sleep** method blocks the thread's execution until it returns or throws an exception. So, if you need to wait for the results of other projects before using the Thread.sleep method, then you must have all the projects complete before the results are displayed.

Comment: The **Thread.sleep** method is not recommended for asynchronous operations in C#. But I recommend using the **Task.delay** method or the async/await syntax, as they allow the main thread to pause for a specified amount of time or interval without affecting the execution of other threads. The **Task.delay** method and the async/await syntax can also be canceled, so you can use them if you need to break or terminate an asynchronous operation.